# Index is out of bounds checking diagonal path in n-queens

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, n-queens

I have to write a program for class to test a 2D-Array. It's the "the 8 queens  problem". All we have to do is write the code to test weather a given 2D-Array has a valid positioning for all eight queens, meaning:

1. Only **one** queen per **row**.
2. Only **one** queen per **column**.
3. Only **one** queen for every **diagonal path**.

The problem I have is with the diagonal iteration. I get an `Index 8 out of bounds for length 8` error.

```java
int gitter [][] // name for the 2D-Array
public static boolean gitterIstRichtig = true; // this is to check if conditions are met

for (row = 0; row <= gitter.length - 1; row++){
    queens = 0;

    for (column = 0; column <= gitter[0].length - 1; column++)
    {
        
        queens += gitter[row][column];
        
        if ((gitter[row][column] == 1) && ((row + 1) <= gitter.length - 1))
        {
            if ((column + 1) <= gitter[0].length - 1)
            {
                int n = 1;
                while ((column + n) <= gitter[0].length - 1)
                {
                    if ((gitter[row + n][column + n] == 1)) // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS TO
                    {
                        gitterIstRichtig = false;
                    }
                    n++;
                }
            }
            if ((column - 1) >= 0)
            {
                int n = 1;
                while ((column - n) >= 0)
                {
                    if ((gitter[row + n][column - n] == 1)) // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS TO                            
                    {
                        gitterIstRichtig = false;
                    }
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks complicated. The mixing between English and German variables is confusing. columns = Spalten, gitter = grid

Anyway... I assume the problem is in `gitter[row + n][column + n]`. You check if 
`column+n` is in the valid index range but **you do not check, if `row + n`** is a valid index.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried to rename the variables to make them understandable, sorry if its messy. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

If an array has a length of 8, trying to access index 8 will always be out of bounds because 0 is the first element. That means index 7 is actually the 8th element.

Comment: I think this will not help him/her.
He/she tries to check the indexes e.g. `row <= gitter.length - 1` to be not out of bound. But later on the accessed indexes get incremented and are not checked correctly.

Comment: Yes, your correct. Judging by the last written line in his question I wanted to make sure he knew what the error meant. Despite checking with `row <= gitter.length - 1`, the line `gitter[row + n][column + n] == 1` throws the error because in the event `row = gitter.length - 1`, adding `n` where `n = 1` is out of bounds.

Comment: @JonahBader thank you for your answer! i was aware that the last index of an array is always the length of array - 1 (since first element is 0). however, i thought i made sure to check wether the index is out of bounds -- apparently not correctly. 
ThomasWilde was correct: i only checked wether column is in index, but forgot to check wether the rows are as well.